# Is it possible to show logs of service containers in open-source drone?

Tags: continuous-integration, drone.io

I want to see logs of my api that is added as a service container. Right now my app cannot connect to `myapi`. If I do locally `$ drone exec` it works, but it's not working on hosted drone and I want to see logs of service `myapi`.

This is an example of my `.drone.yml`

```
build:
  image: myapp:0.0.1
  environment:
    - API_HOST=localhost:8080
  command:
    - rspec

compose:
  api:
    image: myapi:0.2.1
```

Edit: Apparently drone:0.5 shows logs from all services and drone:0.4 shows only logs of the `build` container.

Comment: the ability to view service container logs was added to the 0.5 version of drone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For us, adding `DEBUG=true` to the `drone.rc` helped to see the child containers messages (see http://readme.drone.io/setup/overview/#troubleshooting:68f80267fa3a50980dbb745a782b8dca)

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted answer, I don't think we'll get more correct answer, because new version of drone.io is coming.